# ParseBigInteger FormatException in RavenDB source code

Tags: c#, wpf, parsing, ravendb, biginteger

In our WPF app we have an input validation. One of the input values is a decimal and it allows a max of 28 digits (like `999999999999999999999999999`). One more 9 and it gives a validation error feedback, but 28 9's work as intended.

However, when we try to save it to the RavenDB it gives an BigIntegerParse `FormatException` and I can't figure out why. I thought the size of a BigInteger is almost infinite (if I'm not mistaken it has a byte-max equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, although I'm not sure). Still, you would assume a BigInteger Parse would have no trouble converting a string with 28 9's into a BigInteger.

Here is part of the StackTrace:

```
System.FormatException: The value could not be parsed.
   at System.Numerics.BigNumber.ParseBigInteger(String value, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 1288
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 1010
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 383
   at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 304
   at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject.Load(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJObject.cs:line 251
   at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject.Load(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJObject.cs:line 211
   at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject.Load(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJObject.cs:line 211
   at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJArray.Load(JsonReader reader) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJArray.cs:line 139
   ...
```

I've looked up the source code of the first StackTrace line (`c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 1288`) and found it here: [RavenDB JsonTextReader](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Imports/Newtonsoft.Json/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L1288).

Line 1288 has the following code:

```
1284        else if (parseResult == ParseResult.Overflow)
1285        {
1286    #if !(NET20 || NET35 || SILVERLIGHT || PORTABLE40 || PORTABLE)
1287            string number = _stringReference.ToString();
{1288}          numberValue = BigInteger.Parse(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
1289            numberType = JsonToken.Integer;
1290    #else
1291            // todo - validate number was a valid integer to make sure overflow was the reason for failure
1292            throw JsonReaderException.Create(this, "JSON integer {0} is too large or small for an Int64.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
1293    #endif
1294        }
```

So, my question: What is the max value this Parser can hold in the RavenDB source code? If I knew the max I can adjust the validation class we use to set that as the max, instead of the default decimal's max. (We use RavenDB to save Event-states and our project uses a CQRS architecture.)

Comment: The `parseResult` obviously comes from somewhere in the source code previous to the segment you posted. Trace it back to its origin?

Comment: @J.Steen Maybe it's pretty obvious, but how? I can't debug the source code of RavenDB and line 1288 seems pretty straight forward. It parses the string with `BigInteger.Parse`, but gives a FormatException. Or do you mean that the string might have been changed in the source code along the way (so it no longer is 28 9's at that point of parsing)? (This line 1288 is the deepest place of the error, not the top.)

Comment: I only said the `parseResult` comes from somewhere, I didn't say it was obvious -where-. ;) The `BigInteger.Parse` isn't the actual validation and is probably throwing you off track. The validation has already been done and the `parseResult` variable is the result of that validation somewhere earlier in the code.

Comment: Though it seems, in this case, that this bug is a result of how RavenDb/Json.NET decides what kind of number to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is in how RavenDb deserializes JSON.
Here's a sample. Let's declare sample model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public decimal Bar { get; set; }
}
```

...and serialize it into JSON:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var foo = new Foo
{
    Bar = 9999999999999999999999999999M
};

using (var textWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter))
{
    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, foo);
}

Debug.WriteLine(sb);
```

Output will contain this:

> {"Bar":9999999999999999999999999999.0}

Note, that there's a fractional part in a string representation.
Of course, if you then try to parse this value as `BigInteger` (as RavenDb does), you'll get `FormatException`, because this string is invalid for `BigInteger`.

<s>What you could do here?
Honestly, I don't know... may be, it is better to store the data in your model as `BigInteger`, if it *is* a big integer?</s>

Comment: In my data it is a decimal (an income). Of course it's not obvious anyone would ever put in 28 9's as year income ;), but while testing we came across it. I thought I could just allow a smaller size as input, so it won't be able to give this BigInteger FormatException on the (too large) input. Making the income a BigInteger in our data isn't a good solution however, imho.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: less values pass the test?

Comment: Yeah, when we use regular values like `10000` or `17000000.00` everything works as intended and no exception is raised.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: it seems to me it's a bug in RavenDb (or at least, a limitation, which should be documented). I'd post an issue into their tracker.